# Custom Template for CPT Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

Any way to set a custom template for CPT categories?

Example: When Using `Coding` Category for `PHP` and `Python` CPT's.

Can I set a Custom Category template for `PHP` Posts, and another category template for `Python` Posts?

Comment: When you say *CPT categories*, is this a custom taxonomy or are you using the built in taxonomy named `category` for your custom post type? If it's a custom taxonomy, what is the name of the taxonomy?

Comment: the Built in category

Comment: If you're talking about the category (archive) you would create `category-php.php` for php cpt listing, and `category-python.php' for python cpt listing. If you're talking about single posts you would use `single-php.php` for php cpt's and `single-python.php' for python cpt's, and if you want the content to change if they are in the `coding` category you'd need to add a conditional, like `if(in_category('coding')) { // use this code } else { // use default code }`